# Getting Bluetooth Id/Name

Tags: c#, asp.net, xamarin, maui

How can I take the Bluetooth ID/name of nearby devices in .net Maui
I am now using the Shiny Nuget package.
But I can only get some Uuid of nearby devices and I am not able to get any mobile device ids ..Only getting some ids of watches, headsets etc ...

```
public async void Scan()
{
    try
    {
        if (!await PermissionsGrantedAsync())     // Make sure there is permission to use Bluetooth
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Permission required", "Application needs location permission", "OK");
            //IsBusyIndicator.IsVisible = IsBusyIndicator.IsRunning = !(ScanButton.IsEnabled = true);
            return;
        }
        if (!_bleManager.IsScanning)
        {
            
            _bleManager.Scan()
             .Subscribe(_result =>
             {
                 //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Scanned for: {_result.Peripheral.Uuid.ToString()}");

                 if (!Results.Any(a => a.Peripheral.Uuid.Equals(_result.Peripheral.Uuid)))
                 {
                     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty( _result.Peripheral.Name))
                     {                                
                         // _result.Peripheral.Name
                         Results.Add(_result);                                 
                     }
                 }
             });
        }
        

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {


    }
}
```

By this, I can get the UUIDs but I am not able to get my mobile device ID/Name using this and I can't connect to the getting IDs either (that's mostly watches or other BT devices) I am looking mainly for mobile/laptops